# Web API Url.Link always returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I've the following setup in WebApiConfig

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "ConfirmEmailRoute",
   routeTemplate: "api/account/ConfirmEmail/{userId=userId}/{code=code}",
   defaults: new { userId = RouteParameter.Optional, code = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And this action in the controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/account")]
public class AccountController : BaseApiController
{

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ConfirmEmail/{userId=userId}/{code=code}", Name = "ConfirmEmailRoute")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId = "", string code = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Id and Code are required");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var result = await this.UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok("Email has been successfully confirmed");
        }
        else
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm using the following to generate it's URL

```
Url.Link("ConfirmEmailRoute", new { userId = user.Id, code = code })
```

But this always return null.

I've tried adding controller and Action as well like:

```
Url.Link("ConfirmEmailRoute", new { userId = user.Id, code = code, controller = "Account", Action = "ConfirmEmail" })
```

Isn't working either

The parameter names are same, I don't see why it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

So after couple of tries, I figured out that if I change the routeTemplate like this:

```
routeTemplate: "api/account/ConfirmEmail/{userId}/{code}"
```

The Url.Link will work, but now the Query string params will not work for the ConfirmEmail action.

So I decided to drop Url.Link and use Request to create the URL myself as below:

```
var rootUrl = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, RequestContext.VirtualPathRoot).ToString();

rootUrl += "api/account/ConfirmEmail?userId=userId&code=code";
```